# Message back from windows API

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, winapi, sendmessage

I am trying to receive messages from QCollector as explained in the [QCollector Data Interface](http://www.mechtrading.com/developers/QCollectorDeveloperGuide_2.1.htm) developer guide. The process consists of registering predefined messages, finding the QCollector server window, and exchanging data through the registered messages.

My `WndProc` callback receives lost of messages, but none of those are recognized as one of the registered messages. I'm passing my `Form`'s `this.Handle` in the request, but I'm unsure if this is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HistDataManager
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(string sClass, string sWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        int nWinHandle = FindWindow("QCDataInterfaceWndClass", null);

        uint wm_QCollectorClientDataRequest = RegisterWindowMessage("QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_DATA_REQUEST");
        uint wm_QCollectorClientPortfolioListRequest = RegisterWindowMessage("QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST");
        uint wm_QCollectorPortfolioListRequestComplete = RegisterWindowMessage("QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE ");

        public void TestQC()
        {
            SendMessage(new IntPtr(nWinHandle), wm_QCollectorClientPortfolioListRequest, UIntPtr.Zero, this.Handle);

        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.HWnd + "," + m.Msg + "," + m.LParam + "," + m.WParam);
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == wm_QCollectorClientPortfolioListRequest || m.Msg == wm_QCollectorPortfolioListRequestComplete)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message from specified application found!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

Just to be sure that I have the basics working in c# I created a second version of this app and got them to talk to each other. This works, so I know my handles and message structures are correct.

BUT I never get a response from qCollector. Does anyone have experience of using this in any other language perhaps? I suspect qCollector was written in c++.

Comment: What do you mean by _TargetApp_?

Comment: Try using PostMessage instead.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake TargetApp is the wnd I find with FindWindow("QCDataInterfaceWndClass", null)

Comment: @PeterRitchie PostMessage doesn't work either.

Comment: You never verify, whether `nWinHandle` holds a valid handle.

Comment: Why do you expect that your window proc gets any messages from a different window. You ddin't subclass anything and you didn't register your window as a target for messages. (Cross application subclassing isn't allowed).

Comment: @IInspectable Actually I do - but in this snippet I had stripped it out. I definitely get a positive,non-zero number back

Comment: @xMRi I thought WndProc got everything! What do I use to "register my window as a target"?

Comment: What I see is just a normal window procedure. To receive specific notifications you need to register your window for this. I don't know the library you use. You have registered messages, so who is sending them. Ask the guy who wrotes the stuff you want to use...

Comment: @xMRi: Link to the documentation is in the question. Including the answer from *"the guy who wrotes the stuff"*.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but it looks like typo: `"QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE ".  Note the space between COMPLETE and the closing quote.

Comment: @TnTinMn Good spot - I do get something back now - but it is a number in lParam not a string as the Documentation says

Comment: ManInMoon, Are saying that your `Console.WriteLine` is yielding a number for lParam or that the string that you retrieve using the pointer is a number?  If it is the 1st one, then you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to work with this.  It should be something like: `stringVar = System.Runtime.InteropServices.PtrToStringAuto(m.lParam)`

Comment: @TnTinMn: `PtrToStringAuto` interprets the input as a pointer to a zero-terminated character array. That's not what `LParam` is, though. The value is an [atom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053.aspx) to deal with the cross-process marshaling. It can be retrieved calling by [GlobalGetAtomName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649063.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if it is fine in .Net but i would like to suggest you to call all the functions in either constructor or in init() function.

***Suggested Design***

```
int nWinHandle=0;
uint wm_QCollectorClientDataRequest=0;
uint wm_QCollectorClientPortfolioListRequest=0;
uint wm_QCollectorPortfolioListRequestComplete=0;

void init()
{
    nWinHandle = FindWindow("QCDataInterfaceWndClass", null);
    wm_QCollectorClientDataRequest = RegisterWindowMessage("QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_DATA_REQUEST");
    wm_QCollectorClientPortfolioListRequest = RegisterWindowMessage("QCOLLECTOR_CLIENT_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST");
    wm_QCollectorPortfolioListRequestComplete = RegisterWindowMessage("QCOLLECTOR_PORTFOLIO_LIST_REQUEST_COMPLETE ");
}
```

Comment: The question is not: "How do I improve my design?" The question is: "How do I retrieve a value returned in a message across processes?" This proposed answer does not address the question. Not even remotely. Nor does it add anything useful otherwise.